# How to redirect specifically for one directory?

Tags: redirect, directory

I'm trying to redirect the forum link on my website

example.com/forum to example.net/forum

Most code is either for a page or an entire site. I'm trying to figure out how to do it specifically for ONE directory

Answer (score 0):

You want to instruct the browsers that your forum has moved. This is a "301 redirect".

Supposing your server is Apache, the best is to use an .htaccess file :

http://kb.mediatemple.net/questions/242/How+do+I+redirect+my+site+using+a+.htaccess+file%3F

Here is a list of other methods to do the same :

http://www.webconfs.com/how-to-redirect-a-webpage.php